# 'BalancedBaggingClassifier' object has no attribute 'n_features_in_'

Tags: python, imbalanced-data

i am working on an imbalanced  multi-class dataset, i am trying to pass it into a balancedBaggingClassifier but i keep getting the error below :

code:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_excel('mergedDataset.xlsx')
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
X = dataframe.iloc[:,:-1]
y = dataframe.iloc[:,-1:]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test, y_train,y_test = \
train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.3,random_state=10)
seed = 8
kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits = 3,shuffle=True,random_state = seed)

# initialize the base classifier
base_cls = DecisionTreeClassifier()

# no. of base classifier
num_trees = 500
from imblearn.ensemble import BalancedBaggingClassifier
# bagging classifier
model = BalancedBaggingClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(),
                            sampling_strategy='auto',
                            replacement=False,
                            random_state=0,max_features=1.0)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv = kfold)
print("accuracy :")
print(results.mean())
```

error :

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 13                                 replacement=False,
> 14                                 random_state=0,max_features=1.0)
> ---> 15 model.fit(X_train, y_train)
> 16
> 17 results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv = kfold)
>
> 1 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_bagging.py in
> *fit(self, X, y, max_samples, max_depth, sample_weight)
> 335             max_features = self.max_features
> 336         elif isinstance(self.max_features, float):
> --> 337             max_features = self.max_features * self.n_features_in*
> 338         else:
> 339             raise ValueError("max_features must be int or float")
>
> AttributeError: **'BalancedBaggingClassifier' object has no attribute
> 'n_features_in_'**

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a issue from sickit learn the only solution it's to dowgrade sklearn
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/17353

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by upgrading the imblearn to >= 0.9. I had the same issue, I upgraded and the issue was resolved.